# Bibtex Compilation Issue when generating CV

Tags: bibtex

I am attempting to use Bibtex for a CV. I have the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{moderncv}
\usepackage{utopia}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{pre,peer,conf,talks}{%
Pre-Prints, %
Peer-Reviewed Journal Publications, %
Conference Proceedings, %
}
\renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@{\arabic{enumiv}}}
```

With citations in the following format, for instance:

```
\nocitepre{VVV99, WWW01}
\bibliographystylepre{plain}
\bibliographypre{eric}
```

Where VVV99, for instance, would correspond to the key of a paper in `eric.bib` that should go into `pre.bbl`. I cannot seem to get it to generate the `bbl` files I believe is the issue. When I compile first with PDFLatex, I get the warning, "Citation VVV99 undefined" and so on for all the articles as expected. However, when I run Bibtex, I get the following error:

```
"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) 
The top-level auxiliary file: cv2.aux 
I found no \citation commands---while reading file cv2.aux 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file cv2.aux 
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file cv2.aux 
(There were 3 error messages)"
```

where `cv2.tex` is the name of the file.

Does anybody know why this is occuring? I thought the nocite command was supposed to put the references in the `bbl` files I have created? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `bibtex` on all `aux` files. This means you have to run `bibtex` on `cv2` as well as `pre`, `peer`, `conf` and `talk`.  The `multibib` manual (you can read id running `textbook multibib` from the command line) clearly specify this (section 1.2). The manual also gives instructions on how to generate a script (bash) file to run it on all files